# How to set a label to a variable in Watir

Tags: ruby, variables, if-statement, automation, watir-webdriver

I am trying to set some html contents to a variable so i can perform some if statements. But I get this instead:

```
  Fail #<Watir::Browser:0x00000004440b98>
```

It looks like my variable isnt set to text i want to set.

my html:

```
<label class="col-lg-12 control-label ng-binding" ng-show="productionReport.Status == 2 &amp;&amp; productionReport.ReadyForPublishDate" style="">Text 1</label>
```

My Watir code:

```
msgText = 'Text 1'
msgText2 = @browser.label(:xpath, '/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div/form/div/div/div[2]/label')
if (msgText == msgText2)
            puts 'Pass' "#{msgText2}"
else 
        puts 'Fail' "#{msgText2}"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `msgText2` (ie `@browser.label`) is being set to a Watir::Label element rather than its text.

To get the text of the label, you need to call the `text` method. For example:

```
msgText2_element = @browser.label(:xpath, '/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div/form/div/div/div[2]/label')
msgText2 = msgText2_element.text
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried your code but it prints empty string.

Comment: @Ahsan Justin Ko's answer correctly explains the problem with your code, and this solution should definitely work. Double-check your XPath, perhaps.